# Unable to login to Mozilla Weave on 2nd PC

Tags: sync, firefox

Just installed on two PCs. Installation no problem, but on 2nd PC the Weave login in disabled (grayed out), so obviously the 2nd PC cannot sync Firefox until I am able to login. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to update the Weave plugin? I had the same problem, did the update, and problem solved. Greetings.

Comment: The latest version of Weave is 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Weave is outdate. Latest version was 1.2.x or so, and now they use the "Firefox Sync" name.

Install this one ([FF sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/)). Of course you can login with your data from Weave whatever version.

---

Information: http://linuxers.org/article/weave-be-rebranded-firefox-sync

(whoops I just realised the 0% accept rate and the date of the ask. Well, maybe it helps someone later.)